# Need a solution for this concatenate of 4 cell values which is resulting in line break

Tags: excel, vba

I tried:

```
Sheet7.Cells(j, 5) = Sheet7.Cells(j, 4) + "," + Sheet7.Cells(j, 1) + "," + Sheet7.Cells(j, 2) + "," & Sheet7.Cells(j, 3)
```

And my output was:

```
2016-07-28
,00000152009908151933
,46389789462,789764654523279
```

But I was expecting to be in 1 line as the following:

```
2016-07-28,00000152009908151933,46389789462,789764654523279
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To"). Afterwards, please update your question with the `VBA` code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. Even recording a macro is a way to start.

Comment: Replace(Sheet7.Cells(j, 4), Chr(10), "")




I used this and was able to get rid off the line break.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break your output into two lines use the formula this way:

```
Sheet7.Cells(j, 5) = Sheet7.Cells(j, 4) + "," + Sheet7.Cells(j, 1) + "," + vblf + Sheet7.Cells(j, 2) + "," & Sheet7.Cells(j, 3)
```

Comment: I think this is not a valid answer as it is doing the opposite of what the OP is asking. Their goal is to output everything in a *single* line, but they are currently not able to do so with their code. You are suggesting to output it in *two* lines

Comment: Thanks for the revert. But yes, as victor said..am looking for something in one single line.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably facing a viewing problem. Add another line to your code which will expand the column 5 for viewing entire cell in one row or line.

Sheet7.Cells(j, 5) = Sheet7.Cells(j, 4) + "," + Sheet7.Cells(j, 1) + "," + Sheet7.Cells(j, 2) + "," & Sheet7.Cells(j, 3)

Sheet7.Columns(5).EntireColumn.AutoFit